# guardar el estado de una componente en otro componente hijo que esta en ona ruta diferente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, component

Hola chicos tengo estos 2 componentes necesito lo siguiente

Cuando le dé clic a cualquier botón del componente principal, me debe mostrar una página con un
botón que diga “Finalizar tarea #X” (la X depende de la tarea), y cuando le dé clic a ese botón, me debe llevar de nuevo a la página del componente principal, escondiendo el botón de la pagina de la tarea que acabo de realizar.

paso a dejar componente padre:

```
import { Flex, Button, Box } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const SectionBox1 = () => {
    const [tareaCompletada, setTareaCompletada] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const storedTareaCompletada = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listaTareas'));
        if (storedTareaCompletada) {
        setTareaCompletada(storedTareaCompletada);
        }
    }, []);

    const handleTareaCompletada = (completada) => {
        setTareaCompletada(completada);
        localStorage.setItem('listaTareas', JSON.stringify(completada));
    };

    return (
        <Flex direction='row' justify='space-evenly' align='center' w='60vw' h='30vh'>
            <Flex direction='column' border='2px solid white' w='300px' h='250px' textAlign='center'>
                <Box borderBottom='5px solid white'>
                    <h1>TAREA #1</h1>
                </Box>
                <Button
                    marginLeft='50px'
                    marginTop='4rem'
                    as='button'
                    height='40px'
                    lineHeight='1.2'
                    transition='all 0.2s cubic-bezier(.08,.52,.52,1)'
                    border='1px'
                    px='8px'
                    borderRadius='20px'
                    fontSize='14px'
                    fontWeight='semibold'
                    bg='#f5f6f7'
                    w='200px'
                    borderColor='#ccd0d5'
                    color='#4b4f56'
                    _hover={{ bg: '#ebedf0' }}
                    _active={{
                        bg: '#dddfe2',
                        transform: 'scale(0.98)',
                        borderColor: '#bec3c9',
                    }}
                    _focus={{
                        boxShadow: '0 0 1px 2px rgba(88, 144, 255, .75), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15)',
                    }}
                    disabled={tareaCompletada} // Deshabilita el botón cuando la tarea esté completada
                    onClick={() => handleTareaCompletada(true)}
                    >
                    <Link to='/ruta/tarea1'>Hacer tarea #1</Link>
                </Button>
            </Flex>
            <Flex direction='column' border='2px solid white' w='300px' h='250px' textAlign='center'>
                <Box borderBottom='5px solid white'>
                    <h1>TAREA #2</h1>
                </Box>
                <Button
                    marginLeft='50px'
                    marginTop='4rem'
                    as='button'
                    height='40px'
                    lineHeight='1.2'
                    transition='all 0.2s cubic-bezier(.08,.52,.52,1)'
                    border='1px'
                    px='8px'
                    borderRadius='20px'
                    fontSize='14px'
                    fontWeight='semibold'
                    bg='#f5f6f7'
                    w='200px'
                    borderColor='#ccd0d5'
                    color='#4b4f56'
                    _hover={{ bg: '#ebedf0' }}
                    _active={{
                        bg: '#dddfe2',
                        transform: 'scale(0.98)',
                        borderColor: '#bec3c9',
                    }}
                    _focus={{
                        boxShadow:
                        '0 0 1px 2px rgba(88, 144, 255, .75), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15)',
                    }}
                >
                    <Link to='/ruta/tarea2'>Hacer tarea #2</Link> 
                </Button>
            </Flex>
        </Flex>
    )
}
```

componente hijo

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Box, Button, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Tarea1 = () => {
    const [tareaCompletada, setTareaCompletada] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('tareaCompletada', JSON.stringify(tareaCompletada));
      }, [tareaCompletada]);

    const handleBotonClick = () => {
        setTareaCompletada(true);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            handleBotonClick();
    };
}, []);

  return (
    <Flex direction='column' justify='center' alignItems='center' alignContent='center' w='100vw' h='100vh'>
      <Box p='1rem' border='2px solid white' borderRadius='20px'>
        <h2>Aquí completarás la tarea</h2>
      </Box>
      <Button
        marginTop='1.5rem'
        height='40px'
        lineHeight='1.2'
        transition='all 0.2s cubic-bezier(.08,.52,.52,1)'
        border='1px'
        px='8px'
        borderRadius='20px'
        fontSize='14px'
        fontWeight='semibold'
        bg='#f5f6f7'
        w='200px'
        borderColor='#ccd0d5'
        color='#4b4f56'
        _hover={{ bg: '#ebedf0' }}
        _active={{
          bg: '#dddfe2',
          transform: 'scale(0.98)',
          borderColor: '#bec3c9',
        }}
        _focus={{
          boxShadow: '0 0 1px 2px rgba(88, 144, 255, .75), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15)',
        }}
        onClick={handleBotonClick}
      >
        <Link to='/'>Ir atrás</Link>
      </Button>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

estos son los 2 componentes y necesito porder desabilitar el boton del componente 1 despues de validar que el boton de la tarea esta ok

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: puedes usar Context para que las tareas realizadas sean accesibles desde toda tu app o comprobar las tareas realizadas almacenadas en localStorage cada que se renderice el componente SectionBox1